# Using Qtip2 inside an Angular Directive Template

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use Qtip2 with Angular Directive Template.

Inside my Angular Directive Template are buttons and they are inside an angular ng-repeat loop.
And inside this ng-repeat loop, there is a unique variable called 'value' which is the name of each button.

So what I want is to use Qtip2 with this directive template that will display the 'value' tooltip.

The directive template looks something like this:

```
<button ng-mouseover="qtipping(value)"> {{value}} </button>
```

How do I implement this? I tried add an attribute to the button with a ng-mouseover="qtipping(value)" but it doesn't work.

The code inside my link function looks something like this:

```
link: function(scope,element,attrs){
    scope.qtipping = function(value){
        $("button").qtip({
            content:{
                text: value //This will appear the unique name of the button
            }
        })
    }
}
```

When I run the code, basically nothing happens. I mouseover the buttons with nothing. No error too.

The code that works is:

```
link: function(scope,element,attrs){
        $("button").qtip({
            content:{
                text: "TestMessage" //This will appear the unique name of the button
            }
        })
}
```

Without using a function. But I need a FUNCTION to extract the 'value' from the template dom. How do I go about doing this? I am also quite noob in Angular.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a separate directive to show qtip on each button. Here is a directive to add qtip to an element:

```
.directive('qtip', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      $(element).qtip({
        content: {
          text: attrs.qtipText
        }
      });
    }
  };
}
```

use it like this:

```
<button qtip qtip-text="{{value}}"> {{value}} </button>
```

**EDIT:** The code had a missing brace. Fixed that, here is a working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/uVdpf5gLILd82dr62V03?p=preview

Comment: Hi, I have tried the above solution but it still doesn't work. I have console log it. It is all correct with no error. But the qtip part of the code just doesn't show up or gets executed. Which is the $(element).qtip({}) part. I have no idea why is that

Comment: @GeoffreyTefeng, My code had a missing brace. Check out my edit. Sorry about that.

Comment: Worked for me, I used "title" attribute instead of "qtip-text"/"qtipText" to get this working. Don't forget the final bracket too.